# Word add-in DocumentBeforeClose event only firing once

Tags: c#, events, ms-word, vsto

I'm working on a Word application add-in in c#.

I am trying to use the `DocumentBeforeClose` event:

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document vstoDoc = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);

vstoDoc.BeforeClose += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(ThisDocument_BeforeClose);
```

I can handle it, but when I try to close and open a document (not the entire application), I can't handle this event any more.

edit:

DocumentBeforeClose is nice.

But how i can use ref bool Cancel

I try:

```
void Application_DocumentBeforeClose(_Word.Document Doc, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Cancel = true;
}
```

But its doestn work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handler you register is on one specific document. If you close it, the event handler doesn't count for subsequent documents.

If you don't want the `BeforeClose` event fire for one specific document, but for any document that gets opened, use the [`Application.DocumentBeforeClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_event.documentbeforeclose(v=office.15).aspx) event.

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DocumentBeforeClose += Application_DocumentBeforeClose;

void Application_DocumentBeforeClose(_Word.Document Doc, ref bool Cancel)
{
    // Doc is the document getting closed
}
```